# Node.js and mongoose update parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

***task.js***

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var taskSchema = new Schema({
   status: {type: String, default: 'TO-DO'},
   contents: String,
   createDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
   author: {type:String, defafult:'Chris'}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);
```

***task-controller.js***

```
var Task = require('../models/task.js');

exports.update = function(req, res) {
   Task.update({
       contents : req.body.contents
   }, {
       status : req.body.status
   }, function(err, numberAffected, raw) {
       if (err) {
           throw err;
       }
       console.log('The number of updated documents was %d', numberAffected);
       console.log('The raw reponse from MongoDB was', raw);
   });
      res.redirect('/');
      res.end();
   };
```

At task-controller.js, You can see "numberAffected" and "raw" parameters.
However when I execute the code, the console displays

> The number of updated documents was NaN
>
> The raw reponse from MongoDB was undefined

So I searched the reference, but I can't find those kinds of parameters.
Are those parameters valid?

Comment: why does your schema say `contents: String` instead of `contents: {type: String}`? Or is it a typo in your question?

Comment: I thought a bracket can be omitted if there is only one option. Is it incorrect?

Comment: You might be correct, but I haven't tried it, and haven't seen it anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because Model.update returns a callback with only two parameters first parameter being err and second numAffected (which is Object not a number) as follows :

```
var Task = require('../models/task.js');

exports.update = function(req, res) {
   Task.update({
       contents : req.body.contents
   }, {
       status : req.body.status
   }, function(err, numberAffected) {
       //numberAffected is Object
       if (err) {
           throw err;
       }
       console.log('The number of updated documents was ', numberAffected); //Remove %d as numberAffected is not a number
   });
      res.redirect('/');
      res.end();
   };
```